# how to return a mixed case alphanumeric string with DBMS_RANDOM oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, random

based on the specification here (section STRING function, parameters)

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm

there is no way to set a mixed case alphanumeric string. Is this feature not supported or 
are there further settings to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function is ok.....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_RANDOM_STRING(v_length NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    lKey VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   FOR I IN 1..v_length LOOP
      lKey := lKey || substr( 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', mod(abs(dbms_random.random), 62)+1, 1);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN lKey;
END;
/
```

Comment: should I understand from this that the feature is not supported by default?

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can just make a simple query based on function from **cagcowboy**. Something like:

```
SELECT LISTAGG (
          (SELECT SUBSTR ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rnd, 1)
             FROM DUAL),
          '')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl)
  FROM (SELECT     LEVEL AS lvl, MOD (ABS (DBMS_RANDOM.random), 62) + 1 AS rnd
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10)
```

Where 10 is the length of your random string